# Parsing arguments in C

Tags: c

I started learning C in university but only for one semester. I'm interested in learning a bit more about the language and started a small command line application.
I want to parse command line arguments. Since every command line application has to deal with this, I wonder if somebody has ever released a library to deal with that. Sure, I could do some decision making with if-else or switch statements, but I think it gets more complicated when I want to accept commands starting with '-' or '--' and also print a list of available commands, including descriptions. 
Since I want to make my app for Windows and Linux, I can't use the GNU C Library which is posix-only (but has a helper for command handling).

Is there a nice way to achive tat or do I need to start from scratch?

Comment: [getopt](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt)

Comment: Yes. There is a nice way to achieve that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The getopt will help you to parse the command line argument.

getopt :-

In getopt man page,

Syntax :

```
   int getopt(int argc, char * const argv[], const char *optstring);
```

The  getopt() function parses the command-line arguments.  Its arguments argc and argv are the argument count and array as passed to the main()  function on program invocation.  An element of argv that starts with '-' (and is not exactly  "-"  or "--")  is  an  option  element.   The  characters  of this element (aside from the initial '-') are option characters.  If     getopt() is called repeatedly, it returns successively each of the option characters from each of the option elements.

Example:-

```
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <stdio.h>

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       int flags, opt;
       int nsecs, tfnd;

       nsecs = 0;
       tfnd = 0;
       flags = 0;
       while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "nt:")) != -1) {
           switch (opt) {
           case 'n':
               flags = 1;
               break;
           case 't':
               nsecs = atoi(optarg);
               tfnd = 1;
               break;
           default: /* '?' */
               fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-t nsecs] [-n] name\n",
                       argv[0]);
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }
       }

       printf("flags=%d; tfnd=%d; optind=%d\n", flags, tfnd, optind);

       if (optind >= argc) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Expected argument after options\n");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       printf("name argument = %s\n", argv[optind]);

       /* Other code omitted */

       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```

Try the link for [getopt(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) man page to read more about the getopt function.